# Can a field in my Class be the sum of two other fields? (Java)

Tags: java, initialization, field

My code is something like this:

```
Public Class Location
{
    private int piecesA;
    private int piecesB;
    private int pieces = piecesA + piecesB;

    //methods etc.
}
```

There are many places in my code where having the separately defined "pieces" field is useful and makes it much more concise. When I try to use it by changing the values of "piecesA" and "piecesB" however, the value of "pieces" doesn't change.
Can anyone explain why this is the case (having one field be the sum of two others is not allowable), or suggest alternative methods of achieving the same thing?

Comment: Read about references in java.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here is you're thinking on a declarative way, stating that pieces will be always the sum of piecesA and piecesB fields. 
But Java is not a declarative programming language, it's imperative, thus evaluating each expression at runtime. Since you have the expression on the field declaration, the sum will be evaluated and the pieces field is assigned.

The best way to achieve what you want is not to have a field but a method that evaluated the sum each time it is invoked:

```
private int piecesA;
private int piecesB;

public int getPieces() {
    return piecesA + piecesB;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The declared value doesn't recalculate every time one of the parts changes; it's a compile time constant.

Instead, use a getter:

```
public int getPieces() {
    return piecesA + piecesB;
}
```

Comment: The variable is not a constant; it lacks the final modifier. The expression is always equal to zero -- but is not technically considered a constant expression, because it contains variables that are not constants.

Comment: @AndyThomas I wasn't talking about the variable; I was talking about the calculation. The expression `piecesA + piecesB` is a compile time constant (of zero)

Comment: Didn't know which you were referring to; the antecedent was "the declaration." That said, the expression always evaluates to zero -- but it's not considered a constant expression according to the JLS. Given that, it might not be evaluated at compile-time.